# Invert adjacency matrix using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have big undirected graph (about ~200k nodes). I want to invert its adjacency matrix. So if A and B is connected in first graph, they should't be connected in the new one. How could I approach this?

Comment: [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generators.html)

Comment: I'm trying to use [non neighbors func.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.non_neighbors.html#networkx.classes.function.non_neighbors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the  [Complement Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph). You have a function in NetworkX to do exactly that. Here's an example:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(((1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(4,5),(5,1),(8,2)))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightgreen',node_size=500)
```

[image]

```
H = nx.complement(G)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
nx.draw(H, with_labels=True, node_color='lightgreen',node_size=500)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I run your code, it takes up all the RAM on the computer (~ 13 GB) and crashes. And just storing the first graph takes 1.55 GB. Do you now how can i fix it?

Comment: I increased the size of the page file to 32 GB, but the program still does not working

Answer (score 0):

```
def invert_graph(G, v_num = v_num):
    g_2 = generate_empty_graph(v_num)
    for i in range(1, v_num + 1):
        if i%100 == 0:
            print("Inverting ", i)
        non_neighbors = nx.non_neighbors(G, i)
        for neighbor in non_neighbors:
            g_2.add_edge(i, neighbor)
```